# What is happening to my Agave?

Tags: diagnosis, aloe

2 months ago, it lost 3 leafs and some colors in the span of a week. I bath it and it was alive again.

The base of the leafs is still orange/brown and with a little gap from the base.

But this afternoon, a leaf got black and an other is shrinking

It's an Agave "Cream Spike"
I keep it near the window. It never gets sun light directly.

What is happening to it ?

[image: Agave Cream Spike]

Comment: What is your watering regime? Does the soil feel wet or dry when touching it (finger deep)?

Comment: @b.nota I water it every 2 weeks and sometimes I forgot. The soil is dry currently, the last time I water it was 1 week ago. Bonus: I just found a little shoot under the rocks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agave's are all from semi-arid - desert regions of the new world (like southern Utah through Mexico...).
without going anything more than what is in the question: it needs more light and less water...

**light:**
since it has been in the shade or indoors for a period you will need to introduce it to direct sunlight slowly... maybe set it out at 9am and bring it in at 11am for 3 days... then bring it in at 12...  the alternative is to put it in a shady location outside and move it into more direct sunlight progressively.

**water:**
small pots and succulents are kind of a tough combo... if you have well draining soil (and you should), you may be able to water ever day if it gets enough heat and light and air... otherwise, if it is indoors, even in a window, you may only need to water once a week in the summer and once a month in the winter.

Comment: Hi, I water it every 2 weeks. The soil is from the guy that sold it, I assume it is good. I will try what you said about the sunlight. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, today, I'm letting it outside for the whole day. I can't tell if it solved my problem. But I still accept the answer, as you gave my precious advices